# Why does NSManagedObjectID change?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm not really sure whether the format of this question is good for this site.

Basically, does anyone know what has convinced Apple to make the design decision that NSManagedObjectID changes whenever you save the data to the persistent store?

I might be wrong, but that decision sounds quite questionable to me.
There is no clear advantage (it's an UUID! It *is* unique!), and yet it makes passing objectID's --- it can change under your feet at any time when the object is saved.

It is a big problem for me because I use three MOC system (background MOC -> UI MOC -> Persistent MOC), objects are inserted into the background MOC and propagated upwards with a save. The save is asynchronous, as it has to propagate over three different MOCs and returning objects after they were created, yet before they are saved to the persistent store is quite painful, as I can't rely on passing objectID around.

Am I doing something particularly wrong? Does anyone know what is the advantage of UUID being mutable anytime with no notification?

My biggest question is why temporary managedObjectID is offered at all. Is there any point in it at all? Is it just to confuse people into attempting to use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218396/permanent-nsmanagedobjectid-not-so-permanent

Comment: @samson I've seen this question while googling for the solution. I'm not sure what does it have in common with mine -- could you please elaborate? In that question, brianpartridge is asking why he can't store `NSManagedObjectID` in a separate persistent store, while my question is asking why does it mutate _in a single lifecycle of the application_

Comment: @che I'd say no dupe - this doesn't have much in common with the potential dupe.

Comment: @Undo: thanks for the grammar fix.

Comment: It really depend on what you are trying to achieve. but, have you tried using `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` on your BG MOC prior to the save? (possible usage: `[bgCtx obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:[[bgCtx insertedObjects] allObjects] error:nil`)

Comment: @DanShelly, I can, but I find this method very confusing. Consider the case if you have hierarchy of MOCs, each running on it's own queue, and you call `obtainPermanent` from the lowest one.
What happens? How does it propagate through your hierarchy? Which MOCs get blocked, which ones don't? How does it reserve space without actually writing it? Only Apple knows.

Comment: @DanShelly, I'm coming from webdev background, and I'm used to looking at the source code if the documentation is not clear on something (and it almost always is!). So closed source frameworks make me very, very confused.

Comment: `obtainPerm...` will access the store 'directly' and obtain IDs that will remain permanent (or thrown away if the MOC does not make a save). However, you will not be able to execute requests and get these items until you save ...

Comment: @DanShelly but it can't access it directly! It doesn't have a pointer to it. It has to traverse the "parent" pointers till it reaches (or does not reach. what then?) a permanent store.
Then, presumably, it has to lock on the store and reserve an ID and change `ourObject.objectID`.
Also, change --- how? Mutate `NSManagedObjectID`? Create a pointer to a new `NSManagedObjectID` and mutate `ourObject` instead? Do not change anything and wait for the user to ask for the refresh? It's not clear at all.

Comment: Yes it does, all contexts has access to the store coordinator they ultimately use. the change will be transparent: `ourObject.objectID` will be changed automatically to the permanent ID (you supplied the objects and they will be mutated).

Comment: @DanShelly (this is getting way too long, should I ask a separate question?..) 
Anyway --- are you sure? Firstly, `NSManagedObjectContext` header does not have pointers to children, so when a store added to the parent it can't notify it's children that they have a store. From here we can either assume apple uses hidden API to notify children (and children are not enough, grand- etc children will have to be notified as well) OR we have to assume that _at the time_ `obtainPermananentID` is called MOC traverses the chain of MOCs all the way up till it reaches the store.

Comment: @DanShelly it has to be done at that time, as parents of MOCs can change. The latter option is more probable, as it is more simple. But here is the problem, our MOC can live in it's own thread/queue/whatever. Each of the parent MOCs has it's own "thread" as well. How can the child obtain the parent pointers in thread safe way synchronously with no blocking? It's really far from obvious.

Comment: As I said, when you execute a request or obtain IDs, the MOC turn to the coordinator directly. a store addition is done to the coordinator and is transparent at the context level. an Yes, a call to `obtain...` will directly access the coordinator and is considered a trip to the store.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a little confused why you keep saying the `NSManagedObjectID` is specifically a UUID. The URI representation may have a similar appearance to the UUID format, but I don't see anywhere in the docs that it says that "a `NSManagedObjectID` is a UUID" (and as I'll discuss below, it is more than that). Why exactly Apple designed it this way is beyond the scope of StackOverflow, so hopefully your question is really "what is Core Data's design, and how do I work with it?"

What the docs say (in [Managed Object IDs and URIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html)) is that if you want to do this kind of object tracking, you should add your own UUID as a property:

> You can sometimes benefit from creating your own unique ID (UUID) property which can be defined and set for newly inserted objects. This allows you to efficiently locate specific objects using predicates (though before a save operation new objects can be found only in their original context).

The reason that the `NSManagedObjectID` changes can be seen from the immutable data structure. It includes a `persistentStore` property. This cannot be known for certain until you actually save the object (you might call `assignObject:toPersistentStore:` for instance). Again, don't think of the `NSManagedObjectID` in terms of its URI representation; that's just a serialization format. The real ID includes the persistent store, as indicated in the docs:

> Like the primary key in the database, an identifier contains the information needed to exactly describe **an object in a persistent store**, although the detailed information is not exposed.

That identifier cannot be finalized until the object is inserted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must have misread the `NSManagedObjectID` documentation, sorry about that

Two clarifications:
1) So if identifier is essentially equivalent to the primary key, what does `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` actually do on the unsaved object?
and 2) What is the point of temporary IDs? Can one do anything useful with them at all?

Comment: `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` assigns it to a store (thus allowing it to have a permanent id). The reference docs for this method explain further. You can use a temporary id to track an object until it is saved. Though that doesn't have a lot of uses, it's more useful than the identifier being `nil` (since you can always ask if its temporary, and thus treat it like `nil`; you could even add a helper method to do that).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not by any means an expert on Core Data, but my understanding is that the `NSManagedObjectID` is guaranteed to be unique under *most* circumstances. The exceptions are:

- When you create a new object, but it has not yet been committed, its id will be temporary. You can check for this condition with `isTemporaryId`.
- When the backing store has been mutated, i.e. if you're using iCloud and you migrate to a new version of your database.

Since you're talking about a single lifecycle, I assume we're looking at the first option. If that's the case, you should wait to get the id until *after* your changes have propagated up to the persistent store. I think you can get the id from the same object, i.e. create the object, retain a pointer to it, save the context, *then* get that object's id from the retained pointer. Caveat: I've never actually done this, it's just my conclusion based on my reading of the documentation.

Also, the temporary id should persist until you save the context, so you should only ever have to worry about this once -- after the first time the new object's context is saved.

Incidentally, it seems to me that CoreData *must* be implemented in this way. If they attempted to guarantee that the id was unique before actually inserting it into the persistent store, what would happen if two different contexts grabbed the same id, before committing? The only way to guarantee uniqueness / prevent a sort of race condition for ids is to find a unique id *when inserting the record into the database*... Otherwise, CoreData would have to somehow insert a dummy value for each record a *child* context inserts...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it has two problems:

_The only way to guarantee uniqueness is to find a unique id when inserting the record into the database_
No! It's a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). They don't need to "grab" it. It has nothing to do with a primary key in a database.

_you should wait to get the id until after your changes have propagated_
No. Consider the MOC on the background thread, whose parent is the UI MOC. Save on the background thread can't wait for the UI MOC to save, as it will cause a deadlock.

Comment: As I said, I'm not an expert. But what I wrote here is basically taken directly from the documentation. Also, it seems you marked Rob Napier's response as correct, and he basically gives the same answer that I gave. _That identifier cannot be finalized until the object is inserted._ Did I miss something? Why the downvote?

Comment: Sorry about the downvote, I can't change it now =( I've basically misread the documentation.
I find your statement "must be implemented in this way" very misleading. In WWDC2012 core data talk, they specifically suggest creating objects on the background MOC (whose parent is the UI MOC). Now in such an approach the only way to pause until the data is saved to the persistent store would be to block UI thread for the duration of the write (as saves go through the UI thread) which may freeze UI for a couple of seconds.

Comment: I can change the vote after you edit the answer (the system won't allow me otherwise)

Comment: Edited! Is it less misleading now? Which part was misleading? Also, I'm not convinced you're right about having to block the UI. Pretty sure I remember from that CoreData talk that they _specifically_ discussed how to avoid blocking the UI in the use case you describe. Unfortunately, I don't remember what they said ;) Maybe you should be using an NSFetchedResultsController? Then you don't have to block the UI, as you'll get notifications when new records are successfully added... Why are you pausing, anyway? I don't think saves need to go through the UI thread.

Comment: Changed to upvote. Well, exactly, they've discussed not blocking UI by not waiting for save to finish... I am using `NSFetchedResultsController`, but it's not suitable for every single thing.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's not always the best. You can also register for notifications directly -- google `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: Race condition is maybe the best valid answer, and it must be seen not only from one app perspective using multiple contexts. That store, the actual files where data is persisted may be available to multiple apps in the same time. Any database implementation must handle the UUIDs seriously and it all starts with the bottom layer, i.e. the persisted data itself. About the ViewContext as parent for a BackgroundContext, this leads exactly to the blocking you're describing, and hopefully Apple fixed it with the new NSPersistentContainer.