# Retrieving a managed objects ID with NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to retrieve and create a managed object from a NSURL saved in my user-defaults, but I can't figure out how to use the managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation-function. My code looks like this:

```
func setCoreData(){
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let usedKeyName = "timerList"
    let usedList = defaults.objectForKey(usedKeyName) as? [NSURL] ?? []
    let url:NSURL = usedList[0] as NSURL

    let managedobject:NSManagedObjectID = //What do I write here?

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Storing the objectID in the user defaults might be a bad idea, because it is not guaranteed to be stable across application launches. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218396/permanent-nsmanagedobjectid-not-so-permanent.

Comment: @MartinR You contributed earlier today to my question about updating core data when a timer in my custom cell is done, and this is a continuation to this question. You have the knowledge to solve this problem, so I ask you: Do you need to add a process info to the object? If yes, how is this done? And finally, if I can't save any type of reference to this unique process info inside the cell, where and how can I save it so that it will know what to retrieve when updating the core data model?

Comment: It looks like @frank21 is persisting the URI representation, which is (relatively) safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To obtain an `NSManagedObjectID` from the URI representation, you must call the appropriate method on the `NSManagedObjectContext` or `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` - `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:`.

The URI representation includes the UUID of the store used to persist the object. Calling `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:` will cause Core Data to attempt to find the correct store based on that information, and then use the rest of the URI to locate that specific object. Because of this make sure your store's UUID is not changing every time you start up. If Core Data cannot find the data associated with the URI representation `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:` will return nil.

So, for instance, you would do something like:

```
NSManagedObjectID objectId = [[managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:uri];
```

Or in swift:

```
let objectId:NSManagedObjectID = persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation(uri)
```